# AnswerSingle Sign On in Sharepoint 2010 without ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-2010, single-sign-on

I want to implement single sign on in a scenario where my Sharepoint site is in one domain and it will be accessed by users from another domain. I did this previously using ADFS but now the customer doesn't have ADFS in his AD. Is there any way to do this without ADFS?

I am no active directory expert,so detail answers are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use other sso systems that accept Active Directory as backend such as CAS